# How to make APT work in a docker image

Tags: apt, 20.04, docker

Full disclaimer: I am starting with docker.

Here is what I am trying to achieve: Build a docker image of Ubuntu 20.04 with a jvm and mariadb installed inside it.

What I did on my host machine - also an Ubuntu 20.04:

- sudo apt-get install docker.io
- Edit a Dockerfile as follows:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
RUN cat /etc/apt/sources.list | grep -v '#' | grep -v '^$'
RUN apt update
```

- tried to build the image with `docker build --no-cache -t pieroxy/ubuntu-test .`

This failed with the following:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon    413MB
Step 1/7 : FROM ubuntu:20.04
 ---> 7e0aa2d69a15
Step 2/7 : RUN cat /etc/apt/sources.list | grep -v '#'
 ---> Running in adbeec767f3d
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security multiverse
Removing intermediate container adbeec767f3d
 ---> fc21ad5fa8f5
Step 3/7 : RUN apt update
 ---> Running in dbc1b2334efe

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

Ign:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Ign:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Ign:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Err:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security Release
  404   [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
Ign:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Err:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal Release
  404   [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates Release
  404   [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports Release
  404   [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Reading package lists...
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security Release' does not have a Release file.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports Release' does not have a Release file.
The command '/bin/sh -c apt update' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

As I understand, I should be able to install stuff with apt. Without the last line in the Dockerfile, I can run the container to a bash, but very little cli tools are available, making it hard to investigate anything (vi, nano, ping, curl, nothing is installed by default and apt does not work). But doing an `apt update` yields the same error.

What I tried/know:

- The host machine has internet access, no proxy required.
- Internet access of the docker image cannot be asserted as ping, curl, wget, telnet are not available inside the image.
- I have the same issue on two machines: My main desktop computer and a hosted Ubuntu server in a prominent European hosting provider OVH. Both hosts have a direct Internet access.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: im having same issue in gitlab.. I thought it was my GITLAB account but.. did you ever solve this ?

Comment: Nope, no luck so far.